# How does Athos deal with transgender people?

Tags: vorkosigan-saga

Seeing how Lord Dono had his Betan treatment in just a couple of weeks (iirc) and went on to have children, they shouldn't have a problem accepting trans men immigrants, but what if a child born on Athos turns out to identify as anything other than male?

- Did they identify the "gender genes" and make sure to only implant 100% male embryos into uterine replicators? (Kinda creepy!)
- Do they ship any non-male people off to another planet? (Kinda cruel!)
- Do they have "re-education" facilities? (UGH! HORRIBLE!)

How does an all-male planet work, when we humans aren't as easily divided into man and woman as many people would like?

Answer (score 3):

I've thought about this a bit more, and I've come to the following conclusion:

Everybody on Athos is male *per definition*, but that doesn't mean what it means in the rest of the universe. *There is only one gender on Athos*, women (and probably hermaphrodites, too) are - as far as the average Athosian knows - evil aliens. Only people with very high security clearances know more about non-men!

So while an Athosian might be very unhappy with their "maleness" they simply don't know that there is any other choice. You can't be transgender if you don't know any other gender but *men*, I guess.

So I think, they don't do anything about transgender people. They just try to make them feel less alienated in whatever way they can, ones hopes!

Comment: Please provide a reference or citation supporting your answer.